# Garbage collection of String in java

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

Suppose a string in Java is declared as `String s = "hi"`

I just want to know if the String object created above will ever be garbage collected?

if i write `s = null`, at this point will the String object be garbage collected?

Comment: Never. String literals are interned by the JVM

Comment: But if you do `String s1 = s + 1; s1 = null`, then s1 string may be collected.

Comment: Why do you care?  The only thing you need to worry about in (non-Android) Java is whether you have any "left over" references somewhere -- eg, an old HashMap that you should have cleared but left dangling off of a relatively static object somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Take it this way, the compiler will move it to the literal pool. Now all the instance of "hi" will be replaced by this value in the pool , which is actually a way compiler optimizes memory usage. 
No, these values are never garbage collected . However String object created at runtime would be garbage collected.

Comment: So, you mean "hi" will never be garbage collected..whereas new String() will be... Am i right?

Comment: @anand, yes. If you create string object like the way you mentioned: new String(), it would be garbage collected like any other type of objects.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM loads String literals into a String constant pool. This is not done by the javac or JIT compiler. A String loaded into the comnstant pool this way can be cleaned out like any other object, when there is no more references to the object. This would require that the class be unloaded but this can happen if your application works this way.